# Gravity Form on submit not collect entries after resubmit of resolving validation

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am facing a small issue of gravity form in WordPress.

When I have submitted the form without any validation error that time its working fine and entries saved successfully

but Again I submitted the form and missed required fields, again filled required fields and submitted the form that time entries are not saved.

any Idea why it's behaving like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening when you are sending request through AJAX.

You can uncheck AJAX option from gravity form setting. it will work fine.

Comment: Welcome @Ganesh